# Prove that a language is regular

Tags: regular-language, finite-automata, automata, formal-languages

Given the regular languages L1 and L2, prove that the following language is also regular:

[image]

I know that U,*,. between 2 regular languages provides a regular language.
But, the following regular language is infinite so I don't really have an idea how to 'look' at it properly.

would love to get some assistance.

Comment: I'm having trouble deciphering the language definition, as it uses comprehension and quantification in a nonstandard way (normally you can't say for all 1 and for all 2, and quantifiers don't normally occur before the vertical bar).

Comment: the : 'For all 1' refers to the 2i + 1 . and the 'For all 2' refers to the 2i. (Odd and Even)

Comment: I suppse you're trying to say that in both cases we are quantifying over i, subject to the constraint given?  Abuse of notation goes only so far – it has to be understandable :)

Comment: I think I now understand what SuperStar is trying to do.  Do you understand what it does? – Understanding is the first step toward a proof.

Comment: Also, is this homework?

Comment: No. I think that I do understand abit what it does but ive no idea how to start proving it.

Answer (score 1):

Superstar consists of concatenations of words such that

- words on odd positions are taken from L1
- words on even positions are taken from L2

L1 and L2 are regular languages
Then `L1L2` is also a regular language, say `L' := L1L2`
Now `L' = { w1w2 | w1 taken from L1 and w2 taken from L2 }` and L' is regular

```
S -> epsilon | L'S | L1
```

is also a regular language, where epsilon is the zero-length empty word.

```
S will generate L'L'L'……L' and an optional L1 at the end, where L' = L1L2.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your language is (L<sub>1</sub>L<sub>2</sub>)* U (L<sub>1</sub>L<sub>2</sub>)*L<sub>1</sub>.